# Atom showing gray coloured code (non-executable)

Tags: html, css, phpstorm, atom-editor, syntax-highlighting

I usually use **JetBrains PhpStorm** and recently converted from that to **Atom**. I haven't any much experience in that whereas recently I had opened the project of PhpStorm work and that opened and worked fine but when I made a project in the Atom it appears like this.

Please let me know if anyone have any idea related to it, I am in the middle of a project need to submit that.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to open it in any other editor like vs-code?

Comment: Yes its working fine. But anyways i got the idea what was the problem now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, the problem was when I created the HTML file it didn't show any colour but when I executed it, it worked